# How t solve "Variable 'std::ifstream myfile' has initializer but incomplete type"

Tags: c++, string, c++11, fstream

I am about to make a program that will get a record of grades of students and it will determine it's position in a frequency distribution table. The records will be coming from a file. Here is my code:

```
#inlcude<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int const ns=40;

int main() 
{
int y,x,i,vl=0,l=0,m=0,h=0,vh=0;
int argr[ns];
ifstream myfile ( "file.txt", ios::in);
if (myfile.is_open())
{
while(getline(myfile,x))
for(i=0;i<ns;i++)
{
    argr[i]=x;



    if(argr[i]<=20 && argr[i]>=0)
    vl=vl+1;
    else if(argr[i]<=40 && argr[i]>=21)
    l=l+1;
    else if(argr[i]<=60 && argr[i]>=41)
    m=m+1;
    else if(argr[i]<=80 && argr[i]>=61)
    h=h+1;
    else if(argr[i]<100 && argr[i]>=81)
    vh=vh+1;
cout<<"Range\t\tFrequency\n\n";
cout<<"0-20\t\t    "<<vl<<endl;
cout<<"21-40\t\t    "<<l<<endl;
cout<<"41-60\t\t    "<<m<<endl;
cout<<"61-80\t\t    "<<h<<endl;
cout<<"81-100\t\t    "<<vh<<endl;           
}
myfile.close();
}
else cout<<"Can't find the file";

    return 0;
}
```

Another problem showed saying, "Invalud preprocessing directive#include"

What should I do?

Comment: Typo. `inlcude` is not `include`.

Answer (score 8):

```
#inlcude<fstream>
```

change this to

```
#include<fstream>
```

you just got a typo but what kind of terrible IDE are you using that does not show you this immediately?